# Firebase cloud messaging error mismatched-credential

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I hate how firebase very basic hello worlds doesn't work and then we must guess the problems since the documentation is poor as hell..

i'm trying to send a very simple message to a topic with FCM

```
    const messaging = require('firebase-admin').initializeApp({
   serviceAccountId: 'fcm-publisher@igibo-b0b27.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
   projectId: "igibo-b0b27",
   messagingSenderId : 'fcm_publisher',
   appId : 'bla bla bla' //correct apID
}).messaging();


exports.sm_jivo_webhook = (req, res) => {

var message = {
  data: {
    activity: 'chat',
  },
  notification: {
    title: 'Resposta do suporte',
    body: 'Volte ao chat para verificar a resposta as suas dúvidas'
  },
  topic: '46f5b99a-5619-3a6b-a0e7-7ca1757b8930'
};


messaging.send(message)
  .then((response) => {
  res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response));  })
  .catch((error) => {
   res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(error));
  });

};
```

the topic is right
the projectId is right
the serviceAccuontId is right and is an account with admin privileges to fcm

[image]

but still on running this code i get:

```
{"code":"messaging/mismatched-credential","message":"The caller does not have permission"}
```

according to this documentation piece of crap
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#admin_sdk_error_reference

> messaging/mismatched-credential ->    The credential used to authenticate
>   this SDK does not have permission to send messages to the device
>   corresponding to the provided registration token. Make sure the
>   credential and registration token both belong to the same Firebase
>   project. See Add Firebase to your app for documentation on how to
>   authenticate the Firebase Admin SDKs.

what am i doing wrong?
does anyone have a real hello world for this sdk?

Comment: Have you recently regenerated the client token making sure it has the same messaging ID and project?

Comment: i dont use client token... i dont get the message to be delivered at first... im not even talking about show in the phone... IT IS NOT SENT